# Unity2D- Why did my aspect ratio get messed up, and how do I fix it?

Tags: unity-game-engine, canvas, camera

So I have been working on a game in Unity2D, and I was working on the tilemap. Sometime while this was happening, I realized suddenly that my game was weirdly zoomed in when I looked at it through the game view, and this was happening across the board for all of my scenes, not just the one I had been working on. I'm not sure what I could have possibly changed, as the aspect ratio is still set to free aspect in the drop-down menu. My scene also won't show up properly in the scene view either- unless I hide my canvas, I can't see my normal scene anymore even though sort orders haven't changed. I must have clicked something by mistake, but I'm not sure what. Does anyone have any suggestions on what caused this and how to fix it? I'm using Unity version 2019.4.11f1.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed. I somehow clicked the "low resolution aspect ratios" box in that dropdown menu.